# Unable to Install XUnit.net in VIsualStudio 2013

Tags: xunit

I'm having a problem installing XUnit in my visual studio 2013 using .NET Framework 4.5. Any sol'n?

BTW: I'm installing this using NUGET

[Error Image (Click Me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbYAd.png)

Comment: Probably want to install xunit.net and not xunit.core?

Comment: Actually I tried to install xunit.net using NUGET and I got that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using XUnit.Net what I used as alternative is Specflow.xunit and it is working.